# How to view svn diff in vimdiff style in svn

Tags: linux, svn, unix, vim

I am starting to use Subversion on Linux. `svn diff` gives a very cryptic view—very, very unfriendly to eyes. How do I interpret its output? And more importantly, is there a way to view the difference in vimdiff kind of neat style, where both files will open side by side?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it at:
http://blog.tplus1.com/index.php/2007/08/29/how-to-use-vimdiff-as-the-subversion-diff-tool/

This blog post takes the script directly from the [SVN book external diff tools example](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html#svn.advanced.externaldifftools.diff.ex-1):

**diffwrap.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Configure your favorite diff program here.
DIFF="/usr/local/bin/vimdiff"

# Subversion provides the paths we need as the sixth and seventh 
# parameters.
LEFT=${6}
RIGHT=${7}

# Call the diff command (change the following line to make sense for
# your merge program).
$DIFF $LEFT $RIGHT

# Return an errorcode of 0 if no differences were detected, 1 if some were.
# Any other errorcode will be treated as fatal.
```

**Note:** This assumes that your `vimdiff` is in `/usr/local/bin`, for me, in Fedora, it was in `/usr/bin`. If you can't find it run:

```
$ whereis vimdiff
```

Then in `~/.subversion/config`:

```
[helpers]
...
diff-cmd = /home/<username>/bin/diffwrap.sh
```

Answer (score 29):

Edit the file `$HOME/.subversion/config` so it contains the line:

```
diff-cmd = <your favorite diff application>
```

Some diff apps support svn. For example, `diff-cmd = meld` should work fine. However, `vimdiff` is **not** one of them. The reason for that is that `svn diff` gives the files to be compared as 6th and 7th arguments, and not as 1st and 2nd as usual. So what most people do in this situation is this:

**Create a wrapper script**:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/vimdiff ${6} ${7}
```

Save it, for example, at $HOME/bin/svndiffwrap.sh

Do not forget to make it executable `chmod +x $HOME/bin/svndiffwrap.sh`.

**Make it the svn diff command**:

in `$HOME/.subversion/config`:

```
diff-cmd = /home/<username>/bin/svndiffwrap.sh
```

**Note**: Some svn clients do not support paths that uses `$HOME` environment variable. So it is useful to specify full path.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer because it answers the question directly (rather than providing a link).  However, in my case, passing the `--diff-cmd` explicitly, I had to use `${6}` and `${7}` to get the correct behavior.

Comment: Note that if using `gvimdiff` instead of `vimdiff`, apparently the `--nofork` flag is required: `gvimdiff --nofork ${6} ${7}`.  (Without this, the two sides of gvimdiff show up blank.)

Comment: The `diff-cmd = ...` should go into the `[helpers]` section.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. However, after doing this, I can't get the regularly patches with "svn diff > xxx.patch". So I add the following in svndiffwrap.sh. This is not conveniently anyway, Any other solutions?  `patchs="/home/xxx/patchs"
mkdir -p /home/xxx/patchs/
NOW=$(date +"%y-%m-%d-%H%M%S")
diff "$@" > $patchs/$(basename ${@:$#}).patch.$NOW
echo "find svn diff patchs in $patchs"`

Comment: @samuel for patches you can also `svn diff --diff-cmd diff > xxx.patch`, this will use diff over vimdiff specifically for this command

Comment: I tried using `~` instead of the full path to my home directory, and it didn't work. When I gave the full path, it worked

Comment: This has a small problem, which is that if you want to make edits to the original file, then you have to specify the full path to save the file (as $7 is a temp file in my version of svn). Have your script be this: `#!/bin/sh

f=$(echo ${3}|sed -re 's/ \(revision .*\)$//')
/usr/bin/vimdiff ${f} ${6}`

Answer (score 8):

`vimdiff <(svn diff)`

`<()` is referred to as [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) which creates a pseudo file from the output of `svn diff` for `vimdiff` to consume.

You can create a shell alias like so: `alias svndiff='vimdiff <(svn diff)'`

[Similar answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245302/38895)

PS - this is the simplest solution I have yet to find; it changed my life (relatively speaking)!

Comment: Equivalent: `svn diff | vim -`

Answer (score 1):

[VCSCommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90) can do it for you - install the plugin, navigate to the file, and press `<Leader>cv`

Answer (score 1):

I like having the revision and file in the statusline when using vimdiff with svn so I use the following:

**svnvimdiff.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/vim -R -d -f --nofork -n -c "let F1='${5//$'\t'/ }' | set statusline=%{F1} | let F2='${3//$'\t'/ }' | setlocal statusline=%{F2}" ${6} ${7}
```

explanation:

- -R = readonly (we can not edit those files)
- -d = diff mode (side by side)
- -f = foreground (let svn wait)
- --nofork = also foreground (let svn wait)
- -n = skip swapfiles (we do not need the swapfiles since they are already temporary)
- -c = execute vim command
- let F1='${5//$'\t'/ }' (name for all windows with tab replaced because it does not display correctly)
- set statusline=%{F1} (set name as global statusline)
- let F2='${3//$'\t'/ }' (name for first window with tab replaced because it does not display correctly)
- setlocal statusline=%{F2} (set statusline for first window)

Add/change diff-cmd in **$HOME/.subversion/config**

```
diff-cmd = /yourpath/svnvimdiff.sh
```

Or use it inline:

```
svn diff --diff-cmd /yourpath/svnvimdiff <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use tkdiff and tkcvs for svn. Nice side by side view.

Answer (score 0):

The base of each file is stored in .svn folder so you can write small script to launch vimdiff or mgdiff to give a path in .svn folder against which to compare your file. This won't require you to make vimdiff default diff command for svn.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these step

1. Install colordiff
   eg: for Ubuntu
   **sudo apt-get install colordiff**
2. Now you can just try svn diff output to colordiff:
   svn diff -r Rev1:Rev2 file | colordiff
3. Add following code into your bash profile (~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile) to easily access.

   **svndiff() {
   svn diff "${@}" | colordiff 
   }**
4. source bash profile.

   **source ~/.basrc**
   Now it's ready use...
   You can just see the svn diff in your terminal most effectively.

   eg: svndiff

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer from xyz above, the following two scripts work perfectly for me:

File /usr/bin/svndiff:

```
#!/bin/bash
svn diff $@ --diff-cmd=/usr/bin/svndiffwrap.sh
```

File /usr/bin/svndiffwrap.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/vimdiff ${6} ${7}
```

Then anything you can do on the command line like:

```
svn diff -r 124028:125747 ./file1
```

you can just remove the space and it works as expected:

```
svndiff -r 124028:125747 ./file1
```

It even works on entire trees and opens each file in sequence.

```
svndiff -r 124028:125747 ./directory/
```